# Drupal 8.0.0 Open modal dialog

Tags: ajax, javascript

So i create new dialog:

```
$response = new AjaxResponse();
$modal = new OpenDialogCommand($title, $content, $options);
$response->addCommand($modal);
return $response;
```

can someone help me with code how to submit this new dialog?? I can't find online anything that works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create modal windows (pop-ups)?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/229196/how-to-create-modal-windows-pop-ups)