# Replace the default modal with a different one

Tags: 8, ajax, modal-dialogs

I want to replace Drupal 8 default modal with [MDB](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/modals/basic/#docsTabsOverview).

How I can do it? Should I unload default library for modals and load new one? Any idea?

Comment: Use hook_library_info_alter to override the core libraries, similar to the contrib Bootstrap theme. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/229206/47547

Comment: thanks @4k4 but I have two files for MDB (js and css) with everything there, not separated like in Bootstrap theme (dialogs etc.), how to deal with that?

Comment: See [Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-module) on d.o to learn how to create your own library.